# How to redirect both OUT and ERR to one file and only ERR to another

Tags: linux, bash, stderr, io-redirection

Hi experts
I want commands out and err is appended to one file, like this `command > logOutErr.txt 2>&1`

but I also want that err is also appended to another `command 2> logErrOnly.txt`

```
# This is a non working redirection
exec 1>> logOutErr.txt 2>> logOutErr.txt 2>> logErrOnly.txt

# This should be in Out log only
echo ten/two: $((10/2))

# This should be in both Out and Out+Err log files
echo ten/zero: $((10/0))
```

I understand than the last redirect `2>>` overrides the preceding ...so what? tee? but how?

I have to do this once at the beginning of the script, without modifying the rest of the script (because it is dynamically generated and any modification is too complicated)

*Please don't answer only with links to the theory, I have already spent two days reading everything with no good results, I would like a working example*

Thanks

Comment: Using only standard interfaces, the only possible way to do this will break ordering guarantees (meaning if you write line-1 to stdout, line-2 to stderr, and then line-3 to stdout, you can get line-2->line-1->line-3 in your output)

Comment: ...that's true because the OS only provides ordering guarantees local to an individual file descriptor; when your stdout and stderr descriptors point to different places, they're now two different objects, and only have guarantees relative to other writes to the same descriptor (so you still keep a guarantee that one write to stdout will happen before another write to stdout, or that one write to stderr will happen before another write to stderr; but you have no guarantees about in what order a write to stdout and a separate write to stderr will be processed in).

Comment: ...mind that "using only standard interfaces" note above -- I do describe how to do this using nonstandard interfaces elsewhere in the knowledgebase (but because it's already described elsewhere, if you asked how to do it again, that'd be a duplicate).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the understanding that you lose ordering guarantees when doing this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
exec >>logOutErr.txt 2> >(tee -a logErrOnly.txt)

# This should be in OutErr
echo "ten/two: $((10/2))"

# This should be in Err and OutErr
echo "ten/zero: $((10/0))"
```

This works because redirections are processed left-to-right: When `tee` is started, its stdout is already pointed to `logOutErr.txt`, so it appends to that location after first writing to `logErrOnly.txt`.